# Removing cached Google access token that has been revoked

Tags: google-api

In my c# desktop app, I'm using Google's API to authenticate and retrieve the access token for an API. I noticed that the API will cache this token and use it again until it expires.

Using my browser, I was able to revoke the token using:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=1/xxxxxxx
```

I did this to test out how the API handles revoked tokens. As exepected, the API fails. The problem I have though is getting the API to use a new token. It continues to retrieve the cached token, even though it's been revoked. The following code is used to authenticate the use of the API:

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None);
```

How can I get the API to remove the cached token and request a new one?

Answer (score 2):

You have to log out before getting a new token. You can read about OAuth 2.0 here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth?hl=uk . 
Below how I've done that for my windows phone 8 application:

var string const GoogleTokenFileName = "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user"

public async Task LoginAsync()

```
    {
            await Logout();
            _credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = _xmlfile.GoogleClientId,
                ClientSecret = _xmlfile.GoogleClientSecret
            }, new[] { Oauth2Service.Scope.UserinfoProfile }, "user", CancellationToken.None);

            return session;
    }
```

public async Task Logout()

```
    {
        await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
        if (_storageService.FileExists(GoogleTokenFileName))
        {
            _storageService.DeleteFile(GoogleTokenFileName);
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.